# Non-blocking way to lazy-compute a value

Tags: kotlin, asynchronous, lazy-evaluation

I feel like I'm trying to reinvent the wheel, but I can't find what I should be using instead. Also, my wheel looks square-ish.

I want to get the result of some long-running operation (download/async API/compute/etc) in a thread-safe, cached way, that is:

1. if the long-running op has already completed, just return the cached value
2. if the long-running op is running, just wait for it to complete
3. otherwise start the long-running op and wait

I'd like all of the above waiting to be done in non-blocking suspend funcs. Am I missing some obvious doodad in the standard toolset?
I'd also like the cached value to be resettable (invalidate the result, so that the next get() starts over).

Just launching a coroutine will create a bunch of parallel long-running ops if called multiple times before it's done (fails case #2).
Both Flow and Deferred can be used to do that, I think, but both need a bunch of logic around them (like deciding when to start the op vs when to just wait).

So far I found this relatively simple way:

```kotlin
class CachedComputation<T>(private val compute: suspend () -> T) {
    private var cache = GlobalScope.async(Dispatchers.Unconfined, start = CoroutineStart.LAZY) { compute() }

    suspend fun get(): T {
        return cache.await()
    }

    fun reset() {
        cache = GlobalScope.async(Dispatchers.Unconfined, start = CoroutineStart.LAZY) { compute() }
    }
}
```

It might need some synchronisation between get() and reset(). But the main problem with that is the usage of GlobalScope. Passing a Scope to get() is ugly and still starts a new coroutine, even though it's already a suspend func. I'd rather have it confined to the context of the caller.

I can solve it with a more complicated class:

```kotlin
class CachedComputation<T>(private val compute: suspend () -> T) {

    private var future: CompletableDeferred<T>? = null

    /**
     * Return the result of computation once it's available.
     * If the result is ready, return it immediately.
     * If the result is being computed, wait for it to finish and return.
     * If the computation is not running, start it and wait for result.
     */
    suspend fun get(): T {
        val (needToCompute, f) = newOrCurrentFuture()
        return if (needToCompute) {
            compute().also { f.complete(it) }
        } else {
            f.await()
        }
    }

    /**
     * If the computation hasn't started yet, create, save and return a new deferred result
     * and indicate the need to start the computation.
     * Otherwise return the current deferred result that can be awaited on, and indicate
     * there's no need to start a new computation.
     */
    @Synchronized
    private fun newOrCurrentFuture(): Pair<Boolean, CompletableDeferred<T>> {
        val currentFuture = future
        return if (currentFuture != null)
            Pair(false, currentFuture)
        else
            Pair(true, newFuture())
    }

    /**
     * Create a new deferred result and save it in the class field
     */
    private fun newFuture(): CompletableDeferred<T> {
        return CompletableDeferred<T>()
            .also { future = it }
    }

    @Synchronized
    fun reset() {
        future = null
    }
}
```

But it seems unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: Person from the Kotlin Team provided exactly the same solution to yours: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/706#issuecomment-429922811 . `GlobalScope` isn't always that bad.